# Subset complex nested dictionary based on specific keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using yahoofinancials package to get historic prices on some selected ticker. Below code gives me a complex nested dictionary

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker_sub)
data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(start_date=period_start
                                                  , end_date=period_end
                                                  , time_interval='daily')
```

Here's a sample of dictionary I get:

```
{'RYAN.L': 
    {
    'eventsData': {}
    }
, 'SAP': 
    {
    'eventsData': {}
    , 'firstTradeDate': 
        {
        'formatted_date': '1995-09-18'
        , 'date': 811431000
        }
    , 'currency': 'USD'
    , 'instrumentType': 'EQUITY'
    , 'timeZone': {'gmtOffset': -14400}
    , 'prices': [{
        'date': 1599249601
        , 'high': 161.3000030517578
        , 'low': 153.94000244140625
        , 'open': 160.42999267578125
        , 'close': 159.42999267578125
        , 'volume': 702491
        , 'adjclose': 159.42999267578125
        , 'formatted_date': '2020-09-04'
        }]
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code below to get that in Pansdas DF (below code), I run into some keyError [KeyError: 'prices'].

```
stock_hist_df = pd.DataFrame({
    a: {x['formatted_date']: x['adjclose'] for x in data[a]['prices']}
        for a in ticker_sub
})
```

I reckon, because there's no ['prices'] key (any data) in for the first element in the dictionary [data].

I'm fairly new to Python, and have spent good part of my day with loops/ list comprehension to subset the dictionary for where ['prices'] key and value [>0] exits. Then, the next part [pd.DataFrame] will hopefully work!
Wondering if anyone could help me out with this or suggest alternative/ better way forward dealing with this.

Cheers :-)

Nadeer

Answer (score 0):

You can try on the following code.

```
stock_hist_df = pd.DataFrame({
    a: {x['formatted_date']: x['adjclose'] for x in data[a].get('prices', [])}
        for a in ticker_sub
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For historical data, you may find it easier to use the yfinance library.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

df = yf.download('IBM', 
                  start='2020-01-01', 
                  end='2020-09-05', 
                  progress=False)
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that :-)